# Json find in array

Tags: javascript, json, parsing, find

I have this json:

```
{
"response":{
    "name":"Demo Shop",
    "items":[
        {
            "id":3,
            "name":"first",
            "cost":10,
            "description":"First description"
        },
        {
            "id":2,
            "name":"second",
            "cost":50,
            "description":"second description"
        }
    ],
    "coupon":false
}
}
```

I need to parse this json and get description of product by id.

Comment: you could use filter method

Comment: Ohh really and your school teacher gave you this in homework.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

After you parse json with `JSON.parse()` you can use find method to find object with matching id and if object is found you can get its description.

```js
var json = '{"response":{"name":"Demo Shop","items":[{"id":3,"name":"first","cost":10,"description":"First description"},{"id":2,"name":"second","cost":50,"description":"second description"}],"coupon":false}}'

var desc = JSON.parse(json).response.items.find(function(e) {
  return e.id == 3
})

if(desc) {
  console.log(desc.description)
}
```

Answer (score 0):

Try something like this using `filter`:

```js
var json = {
  "response":{
      "name":"Demo Shop",
      "items":[
          {
              "id":3,
              "name":"first",
              "cost":10,
              "description":"First description"
          },
          {
              "id":2,
              "name":"second",
              "cost":50,
              "description":"second description"
          }
      ],
      "coupon":false
  }
}

var result = json.response.items.filter(function(item) {
  return item.id === 3; //Change 3 to what you want to search for
});

if(result.length > 0) {
  console.log(result[0].description);
}
```

Answer (score 0):

```
var json=[{"name":"Lenovo Thinkpad 41A4298","website":"google"},
{"name":"Lenovo Thinkpad 41A2222","website":"google"},
{"name":"Lenovo Thinkpad 41Awww33","website":"yahoo"},
{"name":"Lenovo Thinkpad 41A424448","website":"google"},
{"name":"Lenovo Thinkpad 41A429rr8","website":"ebay"},
{"name":"Lenovo Thinkpad 41A429ff8","website":"ebay"},
{"name":"Lenovo Thinkpad 41A429ss8","website":"rediff"},
{"name":"Lenovo Thinkpad 41A429sg8","website":"yahoo"}];


 var as=$(json).filter(function (i,n){return n.website==='yahoo'});



for (var i=0;i<as.length;i++)
  {
    alert(as[i].name +"         "+as[i].website)
}
```

http://jsbin.com/yakubixi/4/edit?html,css,js,output